# Find a seed that creates a specific number sequence with random.choice(range(128))?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, random-seed

I want to find a seed that creates a specific number sequence:

```
[115,91,45,76,78,93,35,5,29,8,99,88,98,70,40,116,11,39,102,41,124,98,120,57,36,67,57,23,52,34,75,32,117,66,12,19,86,67,62,121,60,5,54,37,65,18,5,56,66,115,32,99,73,70,115,73,123,74,31]
```

I wonder if I could find one of seed that give me this result with the function get() I created :

```
def get():
   seed(x)
   return [choice(range(128)) for _ in range(59)]
```

with x a constant equal to the number that, apply as seed, give me the right top above sequence.

This is a little program I made to expect find it, but right now I'm about 1.6 milions tested seed and still nothing.

```
from random import choice, seed

lc =[115,91,45,76,78,93,35,5,29,8,99,88,98,70,40,116,11,39,102,41,124,98,120,57,36,67,57,23,52,34,75,32,117,66,12,19,86,67,62,121,60,5,54,37,65,18,5,56,66,115,32,99,73,70,115,73,123,74,31]

sd, h = 0,0
while 1:
  seed(sd)
  for c, o in enumerate(lc):
    if not choice(range(128)) == o:
      if c > h :
        print(f"[Seeed {sd}] {c} matchs")
        h = c
      sd += 1
      break
```

Can someone help me to find one of the right seed ?

Comment: feels like a question for https://crypto.stackexchange.com/
My first guess is, that You want to reengineer some epileptically curve, from which seed() is made from...

Comment: I believe it is not certain that your code would ever produce the seed you seek. There is no guarantee that `random.choice` will deliver the sequence you want. Are you aware you are trying to find one out of nearly 4 x 10**125 possible sequences?

Comment: In general, you're out of luck. Even if you find a seed that creates a matching sequence, there's no guarantee that the seed itself matches (i.e. that both sequences would continue the same way). But if there's a chance that `random.seed()` was called without an argument (`x == None`), then the system time would have been used (epoch seconds and microseconds), which narrows down the search considerably, especially if you have a good guess for when the code was run.

Comment: Since the random number generator used [isn't cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Disadvantages), this is potentially feasible, but definitely not by brute-force search. I think https://crypto.stackexchange.com/ is the right place to ask. This tool looks relevant: https://github.com/bishopfox/untwister

Answer (score 0):

Using brute force and assuming that every seed represent an extraction from your set of number (128), with replacement, you have a probability of

```
1/(128)^59 = 1 / 2.1153791001287955166461289857048673274508949854856999 × 10^124
```

for every extraction to get your exact set of numbers (assuming uniform distribution for every number extraction of your random function). Which is a probability pretty near to zero.

So yes. You could hang (almost) forever for that brute force search

Answer (score 0):

I hope it is not possible. 
Technically, it is possible to code a quasi-random generator that allows restoring a seed by a short sequence of results. But normal quasi-random generator should disallow that. 
E.g. for quite common Mersenne Twister the internal state is 624 ints. But your seed is just one int.
Even if you brute-force the seed that gives you’re the same short sequence, the whole internal state actual may be different and consequent generation will goes completely other way.

Comment: Cryptographically secure PRNGs should make it infeasible, but Mersenne Twister [isn't cryptographically secure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Disadvantages). The `random` module docs say Mersenne Twister is indeed used, with a period of `2**19937-1`.

Comment: kaya3, you need 624 iterations to get MT state. TS has 59 iterations only. It's cryptographically secure in current context.

Comment: "Cryptographically secure" means a seed can't feasibly be determined at all, not just that a seed can't be *uniquely* determined. And the OP says they *"want to find **a** seed that creates a specific number sequence"* (emphasis mine), so finding the exact seed that was originally used to generate them (assuming the numbers come from the MT in the first place) is not necessary, so non-uniqueness is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Any seeded PRNG will have a formula to generate the next number from the internal data it holds.  With something as simple as a Linear Congruential PRNG then it is easy to back-calculate the internal data and the numbers used in the formula from the output.  With a more complex PRNG, such as Mersenne Twister, then the back-calculation becomes very difficult.

One solution would be to copy the sequence of numbers you want and store them somewhere, pulling them from the store as needed.  Alternatively read the documentation of the PRNG used to generate those numbers initially to see if a back-calculation is possible.

If the numbers came from a cryptographically secure PRNG then your task becomes orders of magnitude more difficult.